# Jquery returns old value after append

Tags: jquery, jquery-post

I am submiting a form which adds a new item to a table as well as updates a total value. The form is in a jquery dialog and below is the buttons option specified.

```
                buttons: {
                    Save: function() {
                        $.post(mysaveurl , $("#fee_form").serialize(),
                            function(data) { 
                                var $mydata= $(data);
                                var newremovefeeurl = "${removefeeNoIds}" + $mydata.find("td:last").attr("id");
                                $mydata.find("td:last").attr("id", newremovefeeurl);
                                $( "#totalfees" ).before($mydata);  
                                enablespinner();
                                var mynewtotal = parseFloat($("#total").text()) + parseFloat($mydata.find(".cost").text());
        $("#total").empty().html(mynewtotal).toFixed(2);

       alert($("#total").text());           
       //var mynewtotalurl = $("#total").attr("updateurl");
       //$.post(mynewtotalurl , { newtotal: $("#total").text() } );
                            }                           
                        );
                        $( this ).remove();
                    }
```

The post simply adds a new table row to an existing table and updates the value stored inside the element with ID "total". No problem so far.

After reseting the "total" value with **mynewtotal** in the code. I the proceed to alert the contents of "total" which should be the new updated value. Insted, I get the old value even after it was updated.

I want to do another post as indicated by the commented code above.

please advise.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It looks like:

```
$("#total").empty().html(mynewtotal).toFixed(2);
```

should be

```
$("#total").empty().html(mynewtotal.toFixed(2));
```

so that you're operating on the total, not the return of the jQuery function.

Comment: @Binaryrespawn not to be rude to Jekke but this is exactly what I wrote earlier so I'm not sure why you disagreed with it then deleted your comment then accepted this answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be this line is failing:

`parseFloat($("#total").text()) + parseFloat($mydata.find(".cost").text())`

What is the value of `$mydata.find(".cost").text()`?

Also for this line

`$("#total").empty().html(mynewtotal).toFixed(2);`

I think you want

`$("#total").empty().html(mynewtotal.toFixed(2));`

Comment: I assumed it was a number, what I meant was you should alert the result of that expression (also with the parseFloat() wrapper) and see what comes out.  Be careful with `.val()`, `.text()` & `.html()`.  If you don't understand exactly how they work you may be getting unexpected results.